# Nodejs export (write stdout) all app routes as rendered html files to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, stdout

I've build a node app and I wanted to add a functionality to the app that will allow me to export (write stdout) all the paths e.g.

```
/xyz.html
/abc/xy.html
/abc.html
```

rendered as HTML files to a build directory.

```
build dir should look like this
-xzy.html
-abc
--xy.html
-abc.html
```

node app add -flag which would render all app routes > build dir > file.html, file-2.html

Anyone, any suggestions with how I can achieve this feature.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Write to stdout or create file in a build dir?

Comment: so if I have routes e.g domain.com/x.html, y.html I want to std out all my routes as flat rendered html files to a build dir. Does this help?

Comment: You have to provide some code. Routes could be anything. Collect your data and simple print them with `console.log()`.

Comment: I've edited the question. I can't copy paste the entire application code here. All I need is a solution to export all the paths of the site to the build dir. I don't want to run the app and click on each link and save the rendered html file.

Comment: are you using express framework ?